# Como preencher corretamente um ListView com <List> C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

Tenho um método

```
public List <Veiculos> selectListVeiculos()
    {
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(_conexaoMySQL))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Select placa, marca, modelo, cor from veiculos", conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    List<Veiculos> listaVeiculos = new List<Veiculos>();
                    using (MySqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {

                            Veiculos veiculos = new Veiculos();

                            veiculos.Placa = (String)dr["placa"];
                            veiculos.Marca = (String)dr["marca"];
                            veiculos.Modelo = (String)dr["modelo"];
                            veiculos.Cor = (String)dr["cor"];
                            listaVeiculos.Add(veiculos);
                        }
                    }
                    return listaVeiculos;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Erro ao acessar estoque " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

que me retorna um List com Placa, Marca, Modelo e Cor.
Eu adicionei as colunas já e código está assim:

```
private void UserControlListVehicle_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DLL dll = new DLL();
        List<Veiculos> list = new List<Veiculos>();
        list = dll.listaVeiculoss();
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            materialListView1.Items.Add(item.Placa.ToString());
            materialListView1.Items.Add(item.Marca.ToString());
            materialListView1.Items.Add(item.Modelo.ToString());
            materialListView1.Items.Add(item.Cor.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Porém os itens são adicionados todos na mesma coluna, como no print a seguir
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço pra que a Marca seja adicionada na coluna marca, o modelo na coluna modelo, etc ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando o overload `string text` que adiciona uma nova linha só com uma string:

```
materialListView1.Items.Add(item.Placa.ToString());
```

O que você quer usar seria o overload `ListViewItem value`, que por sua vez, tem um overload `string[] items`, que adiciona uma string por cada coluna.

ex:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    materialListView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { item.Placa, item.Marca, item.Modelo, item.Cor }));
}
```

Comment: Entendii, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obg